# Cross Browser Font Width. Works in IE and Chrome, but not on my mobile browser (Galaxy S2)

Tags: css, mobile, fonts, size, width

Help! This box is exactly the same size as the length of the text at 100% zoom on IE and Chrome. But, when viewed on my mobile phone, the box overhangs the length of the text. Is it possible to fix this?

```
<style type="text/css">
#box{
width:375px;
background:blue;
font-size:16px;
font-family:Courier New, Courier, monospace;
}

#textbox{
background:pink;
font-size:16px;
font-family:Courier New, Courier, monospace;
}
</style>

<html>
<head>
<div id="box">Box</div>
<div id="textbox">|1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ|</div>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Personally I would say never rely on a font width unless you have control over all devices and browsers it will be seen on. You never know when something's going to be rendered a pixel wider than it's supposed to be.

Comment: Why set the box width at all? Let the content determine the width. I assume that issue is likely happening because one of those browsers is using a different font. ie two are using Courier New and one is using Courier.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, Eric. Regrettably, it's part of a larger css animation project where I've resolved to use absolute positioning for the elements.

Comment: The problem also shows up when I zoom in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, browsers will interpret font widths differently. Relying on the width of fonts is not ideal.

Instead, if you want the boxes to match the same width, wrap a `<div>` around them and set it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="box">Box</div>
<div id="textbox">|1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ|</div>
</div>
```

A couple other problems with the code you posted.

1. You must put your embedded styles inside of the head tags.
2. You must never put anything before the `<html>` tag except `<!doctype>`
3. Never put `<div>`'s inside of a head. They only belong in the `<body>`

The `<head>` is used to initialize data. The `<body>` is used to display data.